# Генерация C++ классов по XSD (XML Schema) на этапе компиляции

Tags: c++, xml, классы, xsd

Добрый день!

Есть ли возможность сгенерировать классы C++ на основании файла XSD (XML Schema) на этапе компиляции?
Либо есть какая-то утилита, скрипт?

Будет использоваться в CMake.
По сути нужен аналог JAXB2 Maven Plugin, только для C++.

Спасибо!

Comment: Windows или linux?

Comment: В основном используется Linux

Comment: Вот немалый список [тулов](https://www.w3.org/XML/Schema) для подобной задачи. Жаль, он давно не обновляется.

Comment: Посмотри по ответам из [английской версии вопроса](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/445905/xml-schema-to-c-classes). Там их полно.

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать посмотреть в сторону XSLT чтобы трансформировать xml как вам нужно

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

Из платных вам может подойти `Altova XMLSpy` - генерит код для C++.

Из бесплатных [CodeSynthesis XSD](https://www.codesynthesis.com/products/xsd/).

Есть и другие, но это то что я пробовал и мне более менее понравилось.